# What color was the first android phone?

Tags: hardware

I'm doing some research on the first google powered phone, but I can't find out what color it officially shipped with first. Black or white?

Comment: Both from the start. See [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20081216071457/http://www.opt-development.co.uk/press-office/release.php?id=242)

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aT-Mobile_G1_launch_event_2.jpg) was the first widely-available Android phone.  As you can see, it's brownish.

Comment: Also see: http://apcmag.com/HTC_and_Optus_to_launch_Google_Android_mobile_this_week.htm AND http://www.engadget.com/product/g1